# Define data type of enum in C for memory

Tags: c, enums, arduino, state-machine

I could not find a direct answer to this but is it possible to force a certain kind of data type for an `enum` in C ?

e.g I have an `enum` for a state machine that will only hold some of the states, so for memory and perfomance issues it would be great to define an `enum` as a byte or a shorter data type. Is there any way to provide this behaviour in C or even in the Arduino IDE ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: enum you define itself is a datatype. You can use int as an alternative I think.

Comment: Enumerations themselves are really nothing more than *compile time* integer constants. It doesn't matter how many you have, the enumeration itself will not take any space at runtime.

Comment: *Enumerations shall not be the cause of a performance or memory bottleneck.* I believe the standard or common sense implies that somewhere. xD

Comment: There is a `--short-enums` flag for gcc which makes your enum use the smallest type it can, rather than a type the width of a machine word if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When it is an integer in a sense of 32-bit then it takes to much space for me and I would like to force it to only use 8-Bit.

Comment: @Colin__s Yes that is what I am looking for, is there a possibility for Arduino IDE to do so ?

Comment: Probably, Arduino IDE uses avr-gcc to compile. Is there any where you can add compiler options in the IDE?

Comment: How many state ***variables*** do you need? Like I said the number of enumerations doesn't matter, so if you have only one variable for the state then on a platform with 32-bit `int` that's all the space it will take. If you have 1 or 10000 state enumerations doesn't matter, it will still only be a single `int`. Maybe you should look into your design to save space somewhere else?

Comment: @pogrammerdude I need 16 states, and there fore 32 bit is way too much. It is quite an overkill since it could be done with only 4 bits, but registers on machine are 1 Byte

Comment: Or do you mean that the generated *code* is to large for the FLASH memory? So you need to optimize your code for size? Or is it just a simple case of *premature optimization*?

Comment: @programmerdude yes, but see the accepted answer which gives back a result, or more like an explanation why this is not necessary

Comment: In case this is the original Arduino with an Atmel AVR, `int` wouldn't be 32 bits.

Comment: And really, this question is the same concern as for why C forces the program to carry out the expression `x_uint8 + y_uint8` as `int` type addition rather than `uint8_t`. If the compiler can deduct that there are peculiar behavior (accidental bugs) caused by implicit promotion, then it _won't_ perform the calculation on `int` type, but rather on `uint8_t`. Otherwise every C compiler for 8 and 16 bit CPUs would be horribly broken.

Comment: `Arduino IDE` uses `C++` and for few last versions it uses also `C++11` standard (I'm not sure when exactly, but it'd be since about version 1.6.8). So it's possible to define enum with its underlying type:  `enum Something : uint8_t { ... };`. More info: [Enumeration declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard says that *enumeration constants*, that is the "members" of the enum, must be compatible with type `int`. But the enumeration variable itself is allowed to be of other integer types. If you think this doesn't make any sense, it is because it doesn't: the C standard is irrational when it comes to enums.

As for how to pick which integer type an enumeration variable corresponds to, that's unfortunately a decision made by the compiler, not the programmer. On an 8-bit Atmel, an enum variable is either 8 or 16 bits.

Several compilers gives an option to set the size of an enum through non-standard compiler options. To use such features might not be a good idea regardless, as that would make the code non-portable.

However, regardless of the size of an enum, the compiler may (and likely will) optimize expressions where the enum is present, just as it may optimize any expression containing small integer types to not use `int` for the calculation, as the C standard otherwise mandates through integer promotion.

In case you have very extreme performance requirements, don't use enums, but `uint8_t`. But if you had extreme performance requirements, then you wouldn't use a hobbyist 8-bit MCU in the first place! So it turns out that your concern is a non-issue.

Go ahead and use enum and let the compiler worry about optimizations.

Comment: why is it an non-issue to want the best performance even on a hobbyist mcu ? I think one should always try to create the best performing, memory-saving code no matter the circumstances.

Comment: @Kev1n91 Because manual, pre-mature optimizations is the root of a lot of all evil. To begin with, the vast majority of all programmers lack the in-depth knowledge of the given system needed to do such optimizations. You need to know every dirty detail of the CPU, the ABI, the compiler and the C language. Manual optimizations often lead to code that is harder to read and maintain. Readability and clarity is often much more important than performance. Possibly, when doing the manual optimization, you also introduce bugs.

Comment: And finally, your program has real-time requirements: it is either fast enough or it is not. Improving from "fast enough" to "faster yet" adds no value. That's why one should always benchmark the compiler-optimized code before even considering manual optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed before enum constants are basically integer constants. They do not take space themself, they are not listed somewhere in the executable code.

However if you use enum type for defining a variable, then the variable probably takes as much space as an int variable. If you need to save this space you can use any other integer type able to store the necessary range. For example, instead of:

```
enum state {S1, S2, S3, S4};

enum state stack[1000];
...
stack[i] = S2;
...
```

you can write:

```
enum state {S1, S2, S3, S4};
typedef unsigned char my_state_type;

my_state_type stack[1000];
...
stack[i] = S2;
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the C language does not let us declare a variable that is both of an integral type we want, and is restricted to the values of the enum. `stack[i]= 5` would then be flagged.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are not "stored" as variables use memory locations. Enums are used in statements. These statements are compiled and in the compiled result (machine code, assembler), the enums are replaced with their value. For example, an enum constant named `MY_ENUM1` with value `1` will be replaced in the assembler as

```
    mov ax, 1
```

Hence they will take up the smallest amount of memory as is required for the instruction operand.

Comment: Take the code `enum myEnum {e1, e2}; struct s {myEnum e;}; int main(int, char *[]){ printf("%d", sizeof(s)); }` I get 4, that contradicts your answer.

Comment: @Colin-s, in your example, the enum is used in a struct and so takes storage for a variable. Then it is turned into an int.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the main value of enums in C is more descriptive code that is presumably easier to read and maintain. There does not seem to be any real benefit to using an enum versus using a bunch of #define statements. Even declaring a variable of type enum color, say my_hue, the compiler, gcc at least, does not show an error if you assign an 'invalid' value (-100 or +100) to my_hue. And as an undesirable side effect you have the compiler choosing variable types that do not work in perfectly reasonable loops.

Comment: This does not address the original question in any way.  The OP's question was about data types, memory, and performance, in (presumably) the context of a very memory constrained embedded device.  Your answer bears no relationship to this question.